# Why does redis return boolean for HGET in lua script?

Tags: redis, lua

This is my eval command

```
eval "local b = redis.call('hget', 'foo', 'baz'); if (type(b) == 'boolean') then return 'boolean' else return 'not a boolean' end" 0 "hello"
```

This returns `boolean`. But if I return the value of `b` I get `(nil)`. What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://gigacrunch.herokuapp.com/commands/hget

> the value associated with field, or nil when field is not present in
> the hash or key does not exist

There are some conversion rules between Redis an Lua values https://cndoc.github.io/redis-doc-cn/cn/commands/eval.html

Redis `nil` is converted to Lua `false`. So `b` is false. Hence `type(b)` is boolean so you return a string `'boolean'`.

If you return `b` you return `false`. Lua `false` is converted to Redis `nil`.